# Ember Data: handling "long" and "short" versions of API

Tags: ember-data

I have an API which supports a GET of a single object at the endpoints

```
GET /api/objects/id?format=long
GET /api/objects/id?format=short
```

The short version contains fewer fields for smaller payload. The short format might be used in a route like `object.summary` and the long one in `object.details`.

I'd like to be able to use this feature by doing something like

```
this.store.find('object', id, {format: 'long'})
```

The best solution I've been able to come up with is to write my own versions of `find` in the adapter, something like

```
this.store.findWithFormat('object', id, {format: 'long'})
```

and construct the URL myself with the help of methods such as `buildURL`. I will also need to store the short/long information within the model, so that if the version already in the store is in short format, it knows to reload that record in long format.

I considered creating two models, one called `ObjectShort` and another derived from it called `ObjectLong`, but this will result in two versions of the object being in the store, not to mention having to change the API to support that.

Is this a common pattern and are there any better approaches than writing this machinery myself?

Comment: As this doesnt represent well defined models in a regular REST Api, I dont think there is an easy solution for this. The best i could imagine is use the short models as default and store additional attributes in an own attribute. You can create your own attribute type with ember.data e.g. DS.attr('object'). There you could store the rest of the attributes (long version). You just have to make sure that you correctly serialize and deserialize the additional data. 
You cant have 2 same models with different structures.

Comment: just an idea, but what if you'd use the metadata feature of ember.js for this purpose? http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/